# Clean_<fieldname>() prevents a file to use upload_to

Tags: django

Django==1.11.6

I'd like to load files only with permitted extensions. 
Files are loaded via Django admin only.

I have put a breakpoint in get_item_path (marked by a comment here).

The clean_file method somehow prevents the interpreter from going to 
get_item_path. In other words the interpreter doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

If I comment clean_file out, the breakpoint works.

Well, get_item_path is ignored. And by the way, ItemFile object is created. But the file is not saved (the uploaded file doesn't appear in the MEDIA_ROOT directory.

**Could you help me understand what have I done wrongly here?**

**models.py**

```
def get_item_path(instance, filename):
    item_dir = instance.item.get_item_directory() # Breakpoint
    return '{directory}/{filename}'.format(directory=item_dir,
                                           filename=filename)


class ItemFile(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(blank=False,
                            max_length=255,
                            upload_to=get_item_path,
                            verbose_name=_("file"))
```

**admin.py**

```
class ItemFileForm(ModelForm):
    model = ItemFile

    def clean_file(self):
        permitted_extensions = list(PermittedFileFormats.objects.values_list("file_ext", flat=True))
        filename = self.cleaned_data['file'].name
        real_ext = filename.split(".")[-1]

        if real_ext not in permitted_extensions:
            raise ValidationError(_("File doesn't have a permitted extention!"))
        else:
            return filename

class ItemFileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ItemFile
    form = ItemFileForm
    extra = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `clean_file()` method should return if no errors, `self.cleaned_data["file"]` and not its `name` property.